# How to check if the current time is between 23:00 and 06:30

Tags: scripting, date

I am having trouble grasping how to properly check from a bash script if the current time is between 23:00 and 06:30.
I am trying to run an infinite loop to check the time now, and to do something if the time range is between 11pm and 6:30 am.
Here's what I have written so far, which doesn't work the next day:

```
fireup()
{

 local starttime=$(date --date="23:00" +"%s")
 local endtime=$(date --date="06:30" +"%s")

 while :; do
     local currenttime=$(date +%s)
     if [ "$currenttime" -ge "$starttime" -a "$currenttime" -ge "$endtime" ]; then
        do_something
     else
         do_something_else
     fi
     test "$?" -gt 128 && break
     local currenttime=$(date +%s)
 done &
 }
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: "which doesnt work the next day" ... if you use yesterday's 23:00 and 06:30 timestamps and never update those ....

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If all you need is to check if `HH:MM` is between 23:00 and 06:30, then don't use Unix timestamps. Just check the `HH:MM` values directly:

```
fireup()
{  
  while :; do
   currenttime=$(date +%H:%M)
   if [[ "$currenttime" > "23:00" ]] || [[ "$currenttime" < "06:30" ]]; then
     do_something
   else
     do_something_else
   fi
   test "$?" -gt 128 && break
  done &
}
```

Notes:

- Time in `HH:MM` will be in lexicographic order, so you can directly compare them as strings.
- Avoid using [`-a` or `-o` in `[ ]`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_.22.24foo.22_.3D_bar_.26.26_.22.24bar.22_.3D_foo_.5D), use `||` and `&&` instead.
- Since this is bash, prefer `[[ ]]` over `[ ]`, it makes life easier.

Comment: Can you check the current time in a specific time zone? Thanks!

Comment: @tommy.carstensen you can get `date` to use a specific time zone using the `TZ` variable (e.g., `TZ=Asia/Tokyo date` or `TZ=UTC date +%H:%M`

Comment: I'd give you an extra plus just for naming the method fireup()

Comment: @jbrahy that was OP's idea (it's in the question)

Comment: This worked for me, but only after I updated the conditions to

`if [ "$currenttime" \> "$starttime" ] && [ "$currenttime" \< "$endtime" ]; then`

Thanks!

Comment: @therightstuff https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395933/how-to-check-if-the-current-time-is-between-2300-and-0630/395936?noredirect=1#comment1022892_551058

Comment: @muru please ignore the `&&`, for my purposes that's the correct condition and i wasn't thinking about the stated use case when i pasted it in. what i intended was to describe the use of the single brackets `[` and `]`, and the escaped arrows `\<` and `\>`, because some shells don't play nicely with your example.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to be more explicit about the times you want to match, you could use a `case` statement. Here's a 24-hour loop with a case statement inside that indicates whether the current time matches your range:

```
for hh in {00..23}
do
  for mm in {00..59}
  do
    case $hh:$mm in
        (23:*)        echo YES $hh:$mm;;
        (0[012345]:*) echo YES $hh:$mm;;
        (06:[012]*)   echo YES $hh:$mm;;
        (*)           echo  NO $hh:$mm;;
    esac
  done
done
```

To use it in your script, just replace the variables with a call to `date`:

```
case $(date +%H:%M) in
    (23:*)        echo YES;;
    (0[012345]:*) echo YES;;
    (06:[012]*)   echo YES;;
    (*)           echo NO;;
esac
```

You might consider being friendlier to your CPU and computing the amount of time between (now) and the next start time, and [`sleep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sleep) for that amount of time.

Comment: Wow. This is a very unexpected and a great solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can convert the time to seconds since the start of "this" day and then check that the seconds value is either greater than `23*60*60` (82800) or lower than `6*60*60+30*60` (23400).

To get seconds since the start of "this" day you can do:

```
secsSinceMidnight=$(( $(date +%s) - $(date -d '00:00:00' +%s) ))
```

And the test would be:

```
[[ $secsSinceMidnight -lt 23400 || $secsSinceMidnight -gt 82800 ]] && echo YES
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution.
This will work if you cross midnight or not. Function return true if time is between interval. (Otherwise false). See examples in test parts.

```
#! /bin/bash
date_between() {
    TIME=$1
    FROM=$2
    TO=$3
    
    RESULT=false

    if [[ "$FROM" < "$TO" ]]; thenFROM < $TIME) || ($TIME < $TO) ]]; then
            RESULT=true
        fi
    fi

    echo $RESULT
}

test_date_between_human
        if [[ ("$FROM" < "$TIME") && ("$TIME" < "$TO") ]]; then
            RESULT=true
        fi
    else
        if [[ ("$FROM" < "$TIME") || ("$TIME" < "$TO") ]]; then
            RESULT=true
        fi
    fi

    echo "$RESULT"
}

test_date_between_human_readable_time_in_range() {
    assertTrue $(date_between '07:10' '07:00' '07:15')
}
test_date_between_human_readable_time_out_of_range() {
    assertFalse $(date_between '07:40' '07:00' '07:15')
}
test_date_between_human_readable_over_midnight_time_in_range() {
    assertTrue $(date_between '23:30' '23:00' '01:00')
}
test_date_between_human_readable_over_midnight_time_out_of_range() {
    assertFalse $(date_between '07:00' '23:00' '01:00')
}

. shunit2
```

Run:

```
./date_test.sh                
test_date_between_human_readable_time_in_range
test_date_between_human_readable_time_out_of_range
test_date_between_human_readable_over_midnight_time_in_range
test_date_between_human_readable_over_midnight_time_out_of_range

Ran 4 tests.

OK
```

Comment: What is not what, when?   What is the “whole interval”?  I’m often in favor of generalizing questions, and not restricting answers to *example data,* but I believe that you’re taking that philosophy too far.   It really doesn’t help that you use/reference things you haven’t defined, and that your answer is 10% text and 90% code.   Also, you should quote variables.

Comment: Hi, Scott for feedback I expected that examples in test would by enough. At least I add a sort description and quote variables. As you point out. Thx for comment to improve. (I admit my first version was confusing, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation. My goal is to have a solution which is very simple for non-unix geeks to maintain.

When my Linux server restarts, it runs a script which sends an alert. But if this happens as part of our"Maintenance Window" which is defined as between 11pm Saturday and 6am Sunday, I do not want to send the page, because a restart during this window is Okay (patches applied, etc.).  I have tested it and it does work as intended (as far as I can tell).

Here is the calendar for reference:

```
      June 2018
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                1  2
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

Here is my test code:

```
FMT='+%k:%a' # i.e. Sat:23 for Saturday at 11pm local time

TESTDATE1=$(date -d '2018-06-23 14:30:00' $FMT)
TESTDATE2=$(date -d '2018-06-23 23:59:59' $FMT)
TESTDATE3=$(date -d '2018-06-24 00:00:00' $FMT)
TESTDATE4=$(date -d '2018-06-24 05:59:59' $FMT)
TESTDATE5=$(date -d '2018-06-24 08:01:00' $FMT)

for VAL in "${TESTDATE1}" $TESTDATE2 $TESTDATE3 $TESTDATE4 $TESTDATE5
do

    #extract the 24 hour value and the day
    HH="$(echo ${VAL} | cut -d':' -f1)"
    DAY="$(echo ${VAL} | cut -d':' -f2)"

    echo Testing $VAL  $HH  $DAY

    if [[ "$DAY" = "Sat" && $HH -ge 23 ]]; then
            echo '    Shhhh People are trying to sleep ... Sat window'
    elif [[ "$DAY" = "Sun" && $HH -le 6 ]]; then
            echo '    People are trying to sleep ... Sun window'
    else
            echo '    PAGE SOMEONE - time is outside the Maintenance Window'
    fi

done
```

Here is the output

```
Testing 14:Sat 14 Sat
    PAGE SOMEONE - time is outside the Maintenance Window
Testing 23:Sat 23 Sat
    Shhhh People are trying to sleep ... Sat window
Testing 0:Sun 0 Sun
    People are trying to sleep ... Sun window
Testing 5:Sun 5 Sun
    People are trying to sleep ... Sun window
Testing 8:Sun 8 Sun
    PAGE SOMEONE - time is outside the Maintenance Window
```

Comment: Since this appears to attempt to answer the question, I've left it, with some edits. If you truly have a desire to have someone review your code, I'd suggest codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks Jeff, yes, I was looking for suggestions.I was not aware of the codereview site.  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In this particular case, an alternative to make the test simpler is to add an hour and test once for less than `07:30`

```
if [[ $(date -d "now + 60 minutes" +'%H:%M') < "07:30" ]]
    then echo "wake up"
else
    echo "Zzzzzz"
fi
```

Answer (score -2):

Hint:  muru's answer above worked for me, but instead of || (pipes, "or"), i had to use && ("and" operator).

like this:
if [[ "$currenttime" > "23:00" ]] && [[ "$currenttime" < "06:30" ]]

Comment: That doesn’t make any sense.   What possible value of currenttime is *both* greater than “23:00” ***and also*** less than “06:30”?   Hint: there aren’t any.